# How do you create a clear button in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm a currently learning React Native and I am trying to create a clear button that can clear multiple text inputs. I was using the following link to try to make the clear button:
https://snack.expo.io/B1xM4CjIb

I incorporated the example like this:

```
export default class Input extends Component {

    handleLocation = (text) => {
       this.setState({ location: text })
}

    handleStartTime = (text) => {
       this.setState({ startTime: text })
}

    handleEndTime = (text) => {
       this.setState({ endTime: text})
}
    login = (location, startTime, endTime) => {
        alert('Location: ' + location + 'Start Time:' + startTime + 'End Time:' + endTime )
}
    clearInput = () => {
       this.textInputRef.clear();
}

render (){

   return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
       <TouchableOpacity
           style = {styles.submitButton}
           onPress = { () => this.login(this.state.location, this.state.startTime, this.state.endTime)}>
           <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}>
              Submit
           </Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       <Button title= "Clear" onPress={this.clearInput.bind(this)}/>
       <TextInput
           ref={ref => this.textInputRef = ref}/>
           value={this.state.location, this.state.startTime, this.state.endTime}/>
    </View>
```

When I run this I get the error `RawText 'Value=' must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> Component`. That would just make the word value appear on the screen and the clear button still doesn't work. How can I fix it? Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: Two main properties for a TextInput: `OnTextChanged` and `value`. `On TextChanged` calls a function anytime user adds or removes a character. `value` is what is written inside the `TextInput` at anytime. With that being said, prepare`ref`s to your `TextInput`s (3 where each has a `value={YourValue}` << like this. Now on some click, set all `ref.value` to an empty string

Comment: can you elaborate again your problem with full code ?

Comment: do you want to solve `RawText 'Value=' must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> ` this error? or your code is not working for clear?

Comment: The problem with my code is that the clear button doesn't work when I press the button. In addition to not working there is an error about how the  'Value=' should be wrapped in <text>.

Comment: The reason for `RawText 'Value=' must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> Component` error is the extra `/>` you have on the third to last line

Answer (score 1):

You could just say

```
clearInput = () => {
  this.setState({ location: '', startTime: '', endTime: '' });
}
```

As well, since this function is an arrow function. In the `<Button>` we can say `onPress={this.clearInput}` without the need for a `bind(this)`.

Comment: Should I then delete this                                                                  <TextInput
        ref={ref => this.textInputRef = ref}/>
        value={this.state.location, this.state.startTime, this.state.endTime}/>

Comment: Yeah the ref will have no purpose. Also, you need 3 `<TextInput />`, the first with `value={this.state.location}`, second with `value={this.state.startTime}` & finally `value={this.state.endTime}`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ref={'whatever'}` to your textInput component (add one for each text input you want to clear)

Like this

```
<TextInput ref={'one'}/>
<TextInput ref={'two'}/>
<TextInput ref={'three'}/>
...
```

Then use this function to clear the text:

```
clearText() {
    this.refs.one.setNativeProps({text: ''});
    this.refs.two.setNativeProps({text: ''});
    this.refs.three.setNativeProps({text: ''});
}
```

attach it to a buttonPress:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={(text) => this.clearText({text: ''})}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

to clear a single input you can use clearButtonMode property. It will appear on the right side of the text view. This property is supported only for single-line TextInput component. The default value is never. enum('never', 'while-editing', 'unless-editing', 'always')